# Use of cash delta vs forward delta and the mirror image rule

Tags: options, black-scholes, delta, call, put

[image]

There has been no mention in this text of why this formula uses forward delta not cash delta. Why should have this been obvious to the reader?

How can a put be delta neutral at 30%, what does this mean?

Why does the Black-Scholes Merton use cash delta and not forward delta?

Comment: Maybe it would help giving some context as to where this text comes from?

Comment: Dynamic hedging by taleb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Forward delta** is the option's sensitivity to the PV of a forward contract on the same underlying with same maturity as the option. It is a convention often used in FX markets (see for instance [On a FX volatility smile, Is a-delta put volatility equal to (1-a)-delta call volatility?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39029/on-a-fx-volatility-smile-is-a-delta-put-volatility-equal-to-1-a-delta-call-vo/39033#39033)). It is the number of forward contracts required to delta hedge the option.

**Cash delta** (also called **spot delta**) is the option sensitivity to the underlying spot price. It is the number of shares required to delta hedge the option.

From the Call-Put parity a call minus a put has a forward delta of exactly 1, hence the 30%/70% example in the text you are referring to.

A put delta neutral at 30% means the sum of the put and 0.3 forward contracts has zero delta.

The original Black & Scholes derivation considers a risk free portfolio made of the option, shares of the underlying and cash. The number of shares that make the portfolio risk free is the spot delta.