# On a FX volatility smile, Is a-delta put volatility equal to (1-a)-delta call volatility?

Tags: volatility, fx, delta, volatility-smile

On a FX volatility smile in terms of delta,
If I want 95-delta put vol, Is this volatility equal to a 5-delta call vol, and viceversa?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the delta convention. 
The parity 
$$
\Delta_{\text{Put}(\text{strike }  K)} = 1 - \Delta_{\text{Call}(\text{strike }  K)}  
$$
works only when the delta convention is **forward delta**, so the 95-delta put vol is equal to the 5-delta call vol only in this case.

See *Reiswich & Wystup FX Volatility Smile Construction* for a list of all delta conventions and how to build the corresponding strikes.  For most markets (e.g. EURUSD, ...) the delta convention is **spot delta** until 1Y, and **forward delta** over 1Y.